# How to validate a TimeStampToken using a .cer file from filesystem?

Tags: java, validation, bouncycastle, timestamping

There are two validate methods in the TimeStampToken class (bctsp-jdk16-1.46.jar), one of them is deprecated.

The deprecated method uses a X509Certificate as argument, and that's quite easy to create.

```
InputStream inPFX = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("tsp.cer");
CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509", "BC");
X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate) cf.generateCertificate(inPFX);

// The validate method just takes the X509Certificate object
token.validate(cert, "BC");
```

The new method uses a SignerInformationVerifier object. I found a way to create a SignerInformationVerifier (not sure it's the right way), but I still need a X509CertificateHolder object.

- How do I create the X509CertificateHolder from a file on the filesystem (*.cer file)
- Is this the correct way to create a SignerInformationVerifier to validate the TimeStampToken?

My current code looks like this:

```
TimeStampToken token = new TimeStampToken(new CMSSignedData(response));

X509CertificateHolder x = // HOW TODO THIS?

// create the SignerInformationVerifier object
DigestAlgorithmIdentifierFinder daif = new DefaultDigestAlgorithmIdentifierFinder();
DigestCalculatorProvider dcp = new BcDigestCalculatorProvider();
SignerInformationVerifier siv = new BcRSASignerInfoVerifierBuilder(daif, dcp).build(x509ch);

// use the new validate method
token.validate(siv);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
TimeStampToken token = new TimeStampToken(new CMSSignedData(response));

InputStream in = new FileInputStream("tsp.cer");
CertificateFactory factory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");

X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate) factory.generateCertificate(in);

//RSA Signature processing with BC
X509CertificateHolder holder = new X509CertificateHolder(cert.getEncoded());
SignerInformationVerifier siv = new BcRSASignerInfoVerifierBuilder(new DefaultDigestAlgorithmIdentifierFinder(), new BcDigestCalculatorProvider()).build(holder);

//Signature processing with JCA and other provider
//X509CertificateHolder holderJca = new JcaX509CertificateHolder(cert);
//SignerInformationVerifier sivJca = new JcaSimpleSignerInfoVerifierBuilder().setProvider("anotherprovider").build(holderJca);

token.validate(siv);
```

Take a look at **Verifying a SignerInformation object** section of [BC Version 2 APIs](http://www.bouncycastle.org/wiki/display/JA1/BC+Version+2+APIs) documentation for additional information about signature verification with BC API.

You are creating the `SignerInformationVerifier` in the right way, you can find attached at the sample code another way to create the `SignerInformationVerifier` for a JCA/JCE provider based solution.